# Execution real plan SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm working on execution plan on SQL Server (I'm a junior). I execute a query with a real execution plan and as you can see in the screenshot, the percentage on my join is above 100 % (here 139%).

So I'm wondering if it's normal because it's the first time as I see that.

Thanks for your reply!

Actual execution plan:

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: Please post the execution plan in text mode.

Comment: you can update your stats , but from performance tuning point of view , when estimation is +-30% , you are ok.

Answer (score 2):

That percentage represents the actual number of rows vs what the optimizer estimated.

In this case the optimizer was expecting 11433900 rows but ended up touching 15916500 rows.
`15916500/11433900 = 1.39, or, 139%.`

Note this section of the execution plan from a query I just ran;

[image]

Expected 39 but got 40 instead (40/39 = 1.02 or 102%)

Comment: Hi, thank you  !  And  maybe you can answer me about something please.  When you have multiple joins like this:  `select t.ok , t.test, t.sql, e.why from test t left join ens e on t.id = e.id group by t.ok , t.test , t.sql ,  e.why  `

Comment: About choosing index on group by , I would choose non cluster index on t.ok, t.test, t.sql  but for e.why how deal with that  please. ?